# ListView in Child Fragment with backStack is not refreshing but appending

Tags: android, android-listview

In my application, there are some `fragments` and I maintain a `backstack` for them. I resume those `fragment` whenever possible. fragments are resuming successfully and other operations are also performed properly. But problem is- one of them is a `nested-fragment` and it has a `child-fragment` inside it which is extending a `listFragment`.

Everytime when I resume this `fragment`, the `listview` inside the `child-fragmnet` is not recreating. Rather than it appending the same elements below. I mean if there are 5 list-items in real, everytime after resuming there will be 5 more same items at the end.

I have `notifyDataSetChanged()` but it is not working. This is my `child-fragment` code:

```
public class ChaptersListFragment extends SherlockListFragment {

    OnChapterSelectListener mCallback;
    ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter = null;

    public interface OnChapterSelectListener {
        public void onChapterSelected(int position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (mAdapter != null)
            mAdapter.clear(); // I try this but not working

        List<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < CompetitiveProgramming.chapterList.size(); i++) {
            items.add(CompetitiveProgramming.chapterList.get(i).chapterTitle);
        }
        mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getSherlockActivity(),
                R.layout.list_layout, items);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // I try this but not working
        setListAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.sub_category_fragment) != null) {
            getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mCallback = (OnChapterSelectListener) getParentFragment();
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(getParentFragment().toString()
                    + " must implement OnChapterSelectListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        mCallback.onChapterSelected(position);
        getListView().setItemChecked(position, true);
    }

}
```

Moreover when I am changing the orientation, the listview is recreating and there is only 5 items then. However, after resuming several times. the application is crashed with the following logcat:

```
08-21 01:16:09.114: E/AndroidRuntime(664): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-21 01:16:09.114: E/AndroidRuntime(664): java.lang.IllegalStateException: No activity
08-21 01:16:09.114: E/AndroidRuntime(664):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1075)
08-21 01:16:09.114: E/AndroidRuntime(664):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1070)
08-21 01:16:09.114: E/AndroidRuntime(664):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:1861)
08-21 01:16:09.114: E/AndroidRuntime(664):  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:1474)
08-21 01:16:09.114: E/AndroidRuntime(664):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:931)
08-21 01:16:09.114: E/AndroidRuntime(664):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1088)
08-21 01:16:09.114: E/AndroidRuntime(664):  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
08-21 01:16:09.114: E/AndroidRuntime(664):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1444)
08-21 01:16:09.114: E/AndroidRuntime(664):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:429)
08-21 01:16:09.114: E/AndroidRuntime(664):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
08-21 01:16:09.114: E/AndroidRuntime(664):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-21 01:16:09.114: E/AndroidRuntime(664):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-21 01:16:09.114: E/AndroidRuntime(664):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
08-21 01:16:09.114: E/AndroidRuntime(664):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-21 01:16:09.114: E/AndroidRuntime(664):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-21 01:16:09.114: E/AndroidRuntime(664):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
08-21 01:16:09.114: E/AndroidRuntime(664):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
08-21 01:16:09.114: E/AndroidRuntime(664):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And this the parent fragment which is holding the above child fragment:

```
public class CompetitiveProgramming extends SherlockProgressFragment implements
        OnChapterSelectListener, OnSubChapterSelectListener {

    View mContentView;
    static public List<Chapter> chapterList = new ArrayList<Chapter>();
    private ProcessTask processTask = null;
    Fragment chapterFragment = null;
    Fragment subChapterFragment = null;
    Fragment subSubChapterFragment = null;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mContentView = inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.competitive_programming_exercise, container, false);
        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        setContentShown(false);
        setContentView(mContentView);
        processTask = new ProcessTask();
        processTask.execute();
    }

    protected class ProcessTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            InputStream inputStream = null;
            try {
                inputStream = getSherlockActivity().getAssets().open(
                        CommonUtils.FILE_COMPETITIVE_PROGRAMMING_3);

                JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        inputStream));

                reader.beginArray(); // array #1
                while (reader.hasNext()) {
                    String chapterTitle = null;
                    List<SubChapter> subList = new ArrayList<SubChapter>();
                    reader.beginObject(); // object #2
                    while (reader.hasNext()) {
                        reader.skipValue();
                        chapterTitle = reader.nextString();
                        reader.skipValue();
                        reader.beginArray(); // array #3
                        while (reader.hasNext()) {
                            String subChapterTitle = null;
                            List<SubSubChapter> subSubList = new ArrayList<SubSubChapter>();
                            reader.beginObject(); // object #4
                            while (reader.hasNext()) {
                                reader.skipValue();
                                subChapterTitle = reader.nextString();
                                reader.skipValue();
                                reader.beginArray(); // array #5
                                while (reader.hasNext()) {
                                    reader.beginArray(); // array #6
                                    String subSubChapterTitle = reader
                                            .nextString(); // sub-sub-category
                                                            // title
                                    List<ProblemList> problemsList = new ArrayList<ProblemList>();
                                    while (reader.hasNext()) {
                                        int signedProblemID = reader.nextInt(); // problemNo
                                        String title = reader.nextString();
                                        if (signedProblemID < 0)
                                            problemsList.add(new ProblemList(
                                                    Math.abs(signedProblemID), title,
                                                    true));
                                        else
                                            problemsList.add(new ProblemList(
                                                    signedProblemID, title, false));
                                    }
                                    reader.endArray(); // array #6
                                    subSubList.add(new SubSubChapter(
                                            subSubChapterTitle, problemsList));
                                }
                                reader.endArray(); // array #5
                            }
                            reader.endObject(); // object #4
                            subList.add(new SubChapter(subChapterTitle,
                                    subSubList));
                        }
                        reader.endArray(); // array #3
                    }
                    reader.endObject(); // object #2
                    chapterList.add(new Chapter(chapterTitle, subList));
                }
                reader.endArray(); // array #1
                reader.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // nothing
            } finally {
                if (inputStream != null) {
                    try {
                        inputStream.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // nothing
                    }
                }
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction();
            chapterFragment = new ChaptersListFragment();
            if (mContentView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) != null) {
                transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, chapterFragment);
            } else {
                subChapterFragment = new SubChaptersListFragment();
                subSubChapterFragment = new SubSubChaptersListFragment();
                transaction.replace(R.id.category_fragment, chapterFragment);
                transaction.replace(R.id.sub_category_fragment, subChapterFragment);
                transaction.replace(R.id.sub_sub_category_fragment, subSubChapterFragment);
            }
            transaction.commit();
            setContentShown(true);
        }

    }

    static protected class Chapter {
        String chapterTitle;
        List<SubChapter> subchapterList;

        public Chapter(String chapterTitle, List<SubChapter> subchapterList) {
            this.chapterTitle = chapterTitle;
            this.subchapterList = subchapterList;
        }

    }

    static protected class SubChapter {
        String subChapterTitle;
        List<SubSubChapter> subsubchapterList;

        public SubChapter(String subChapterTitle,
                List<SubSubChapter> subsubchapterList) {
            this.subChapterTitle = subChapterTitle;
            this.subsubchapterList = subsubchapterList;
        }

    }

    static protected class SubSubChapter {
        String subSubChapterTitle;
        List<ProblemList> problemList;

        public SubSubChapter(String subSubChapterTitle,
                List<ProblemList> problemList) {
            this.subSubChapterTitle = subSubChapterTitle;
            this.problemList = problemList;
        }

    }

    static public class ProblemList {
        Integer problemNo;
        String problemTitle;
        boolean isStarred;

        public ProblemList(Integer problemNo, String problemTitle, boolean isStarred) {
            this.problemNo = problemNo;
            this.isStarred = isStarred;
            this.problemTitle = problemTitle;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onChapterSelected(int position) {
        SubChaptersListFragment subChaptersListFrag = (SubChaptersListFragment) getChildFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.sub_category_fragment);
        if (subChaptersListFrag != null) {
            subChaptersListFrag.updateList(position);
        } else {
            subChapterFragment = new SubChaptersListFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(SubChaptersListFragment.CHAPTER_POSITION, position);
            subChapterFragment.setArguments(args);
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, subChapterFragment);
            transaction.commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSubChapterSelected(int prev, int position) {
        SubSubChaptersListFragment subSubChaptersListFrag = (SubSubChaptersListFragment) getChildFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.sub_sub_category_fragment);
        if (subSubChaptersListFrag != null) {
            subSubChaptersListFrag.updateList(prev, position);
        } else {
            subSubChapterFragment = new SubSubChaptersListFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putIntArray(SubSubChaptersListFragment.POSITIONS, new int[]{prev, position});
            subSubChapterFragment.setArguments(args);
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, subSubChapterFragment);
            transaction.commit();           
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (processTask != null && processTask.getStatus() != AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED) {
            processTask.cancel(true);
        }
    }

}
```

How can I solve it? If any more code snippet is required, let me know in comment :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not answering on the `listview` appending/refreshing problem, but the app crashing is due to a bug in the `ChildFragmentManager`. Basically, the `ChildFragmentManager` ends up with a broken internal state when it is detached from the `activity`.
See the link below and add that snippet in your `parentFragment` class.

[solution to this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15656428/1162233)