# Tab content disappeared after change page

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-tabhost

I have a weird issue with my Tab (TabHost or TabContent) in my Fragment that contains a ViewPager.

The problem is that when I change the page, then I turn back to the fragment with tab and viewPager, my content or view disappeared.

[image: before disappeared]
->
[image: after back to this fragment]

Here's my code for **TabFragment**

```
package com.halo.mobi.fragment;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.HorizontalScrollView;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabHost.OnTabChangeListener;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabContentFactory;
import android.widget.TabWidget;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.halo.mobi.R;

public class GameTabFragment extends Fragment {
    Activity myActivity;

    TabWidget tab;
    TabHost tabHost;
    ViewPager pager;
    HorizontalScrollView hsvTab;

    List<String> headers;

    TabPagerAdapter adapter;
    TabContentFactory fac;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        myActivity = this.getActivity();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.game_list_tab_fragment,
                container, false);

        headers = new ArrayList<String>();

        tabHost = (TabHost) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
        pager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        hsvTab = (HorizontalScrollView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.hsvTab);
        hsvTab.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);

        tabHost.setup();
        fac = new TabContentFactory() {

            @Override
            public View createTabContent(String tag) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return new View(myActivity);
            }
        };
        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("cat")
                .setIndicator(getTabIndicator(myActivity, "CATEGORIES"))
                .setContent(fac));
        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("new")
                .setIndicator(getTabIndicator(myActivity, "NEW RELEASE"))
                .setContent(fac));
        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("free")
                .setIndicator(getTabIndicator(myActivity, "TOP FREE"))
                .setContent(fac));
        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("paid")
                .setIndicator(getTabIndicator(myActivity, "TOP PAID"))
                .setContent(fac));
        tabHost.getTabWidget().setBackgroundColor(
                getResources().getColor(R.color.merah));

        tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                pager.setCurrentItem(tabHost.getCurrentTab());
                hsvTab.smoothScrollTo(
                        tabHost.getTabWidget()
                                .getChildTabViewAt(tabHost.getCurrentTab())
                                .getLeft(), 0);
            }
        });

        adapter = new TabPagerAdapter(this.getFragmentManager());
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);
        pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(5);
        pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                tabHost.setCurrentTab(arg0);
            }
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }
    private View getTabIndicator(Context context, String title) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
                R.layout.gametablayout, null);
        TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
        tv.setText(title);
        tv.setSingleLine();
        view.setPadding(2, 0, 2, 0);
        return view;
    }
    private class TabPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        GameCategoryFragment cat;
        GameNewReleaseFragment newrelease;
        GameTopFreeFragment topfree;
        GameTopPaidFragment toppaid;

        public TabPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);

            cat = new GameCategoryFragment();
            newrelease = new GameNewReleaseFragment();
            topfree = new GameTopFreeFragment();
            toppaid = new GameTopPaidFragment();
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (pos == 0)
                return cat;
            if (pos == 1)
                return newrelease;
            if (pos == 2)
                return topfree;
            if (pos == 3)
                return toppaid;
            return cat;

        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 4;
        }
    }
}
```

**game_list_tab_fragment.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="top|left"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TabHost
            android:id="@+id/tabHost"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <HorizontalScrollView
                    android:id="@+id/hsvTab"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/merah" >

                    <TabWidget
                        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                    </TabWidget>
                </HorizontalScrollView>

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0px"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >
                </FrameLayout>

                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/pager"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </TabHost>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

and here's **MainActivity.java**:

```
package com.halo.mobi.activity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.halo.mobi.R;
import com.halo.mobi.fragment.GameDetailFragment;
import com.halo.mobi.fragment.GameTabFragment;
import com.halo.mobi.fragment.HomeFragment;
import com.halo.mobi.fragment.NavigationDrawerFragment;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
        NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

    /**
     * Fragment managing the behaviors, interactions and presentation of the
     * navigation drawer.
     */
    private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;

    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    /**
     * Used to store the last screen title. For use in
     * {@link #restoreActionBar()}.
     */
    private int pos;
    FragmentManager fragmentManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        restoreActionBar();

        mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        // Set up the drawer.
        mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(R.id.navigation_drawer, drawerLayout);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments

        fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, new HomeFragment())
                    .addToBackStack("TAG_FRAGMENT").commit();
            break;
        case 1:

            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, new GameTabFragment())
                    .addToBackStack("TAG_FRAGMENT").commit();
            break;
        default:
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, new HomeFragment())
                    .addToBackStack("TAG_FRAGMENT").commit();
            break;
        }
    }

    public void onSectionAttached(int number, int gameId) {
        pos = number;
        if (gameId != 0) {
            fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container,
                            GameDetailFragment.newInstance(number, gameId))
                    // .addToBackStack("TAG_FRAGMENT")
                    .commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (pos == 0) {
            finish();
        } else {
            onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(pos);
        }
    }

    public void restoreActionBar() {
        ActionBar mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        mActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);

        View mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_actionbar, null);

        ImageView imageButton = (ImageView) mCustomView
                .findViewById(R.id.btnMenu);
        imageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mNavigationDrawerFragment.openDrawer();
            }
        });

        mActionBar.setCustomView(mCustomView, new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        mActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Use `getChildFragmentManager()` instead of `getSupportFragmentManager()`

Comment: @Yugesh: where should I put it? cause I can't put inside onNavigationDrawerItemSelected, i got warning like this 'The method getChildFragmentManager() is undefined for the type MainActivity'

Comment: can you add the `MainActivity` code.

Comment: @Yugesh: I have add my MainActivity, I hope you can give me inspiration

Comment: Thanks for your code, it helps me a lot, the answer of thaku huni fix the problem of content erased.
"I had the same problem. In your TabFragment class (GameTabFragment) replace getFragmentManager with getChildFragmentManager.

Instead of: adapter = new TabPagerAdapter(this.getFragmentManager());

Use this: adapter = new TabPagerAdapter(this.getChildFragmentManager());

This should fix it."

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I had the same problem. In your TabFragment class (GameTabFragment) replace getFragmentManager with getChildFragmentManager.

Instead of: 
 adapter = new TabPagerAdapter(this.getFragmentManager());

Use this:
adapter = new TabPagerAdapter(this.getChildFragmentManager());

This should fix it.

Comment: Thank you, it's really works! 
It'll be perfect, if you explain why it happens)

Comment: Really really thank you. This solution worked for after so man hours wasting..

Answer (score 7):

I have 3 tabs and experienced same issue. I used below code and problem fixed.

```
pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
```

Answer (score 3):

In PagerFragment 's onResume() add this:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    for (Fragment fragment : getFragmentManager().getFragments()) {
        if (fragment instanceof Tab1Fragment || fragment instanceof Tab2Fragment) {
            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.detach(fragment);
            ft.attach(fragment);
            ft.commit();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It may be too late, but I was stack with the same issue for hours even of all of the above answers, so I ended up making my own one which consists of:

Using

- `getChildFragmentManager()` to commit the **first** `transaction` (the commit you usually do in the **root Fragment** which is one of your `viewpager`'s `tabs`)
- `getFragmentManager()` to commit the rest of transactions (used to
  replace the **nested** fragments).

This might be an answer to this question [IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id for fragment --- ViewPager in ViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19888539/illegalargumentexception-no-view-found-for-id-for-fragment-viewpager-in-vie) too.

Hope this is going to help someone-else too!