# ViewPager in Fragment with tabs only loading tabs on first view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I have a fragment with tabs that makes use of a view pager. The issue is that the tabs appear when I first visit the fragment but if I navigate somewhere else and then go back to this fragment then the fragments within the view pager no longer appear.

I use a SectionsPagerAdapter as below:

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
    // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            //ClientHealthRootFragment tab1 = new ClientHealthRootFragment();
            ChatListFragment tab1 = new ChatListFragment();
            return tab1;
        case 1:
            ClientProfileFragment tab2 = new ClientProfileFragment();
            //ChatListFragment tab2 = new ChatListFragment();
            return tab2;
        case 2:
            //ClientCommentRootFragment tab3 = new ClientCommentRootFragment();
            ChatListFragment tab3 = new ChatListFragment();
            return tab3;
        default:
            return null;
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // Show 3 total pages.
    return 3;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return "Health";
        case 1:
            return "Profile";
        case 2:
            return "Comments";
    }
    return null;
}}
```

And then in the fragment where I handle the sections is the following:

```
public class ClientMainFragment extends Fragment {

private ViewPager mViewPager;

SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

String client_name;
int client_image;

private TextView clientNameText;
private ImageView clientImage;

public ClientMainFragment() {
    //empty constructor
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_client_main, container, false);

    clientNameText =  view.findViewById(R.id.clientNameTxt);
    clientImage =  view.findViewById(R.id.clientImage);

    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

    return view;
}}
```

I am unsure what I am missing, any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT: Solution**

I figured out what the issue was with the following link:
[Tab content disappeared after change page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27142850/tab-content-disappeared-after-change-page)

Comment: Add your `fragment_client_main` code

Answer (score 0):

**Handel Fragment Life Cycle Implement ovverride method as below :**

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}
```

**and put Hole Code of viewpager code as below in onReume Method as:**

```
mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());

// Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
mViewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
```

**So Final Code Will be:**

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());

// Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
mViewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but unfortunately it still isn't showing up once I return to it after opening it the first time.