# Nested fragments getchildfragmentmanager causing crash

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-support-library, android-nested-fragment

I have viewPager which contains fragments each of these fragment has viewpager to display Images and banners

now to each fragment Image adapter I am passing  getChildFragmentManager() as below

```
CarouselAdapter carouselAdapter = new CarouselAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
```

But above code is causing crash while changing viewpager tabs showing following message

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f1000ef
```

But if I pass getFragmentManager() it is not crashing but adapter goes blank for some time any Idea how to handle nested fragments.

I am using FragmentPagerAdapter for both viewpagers but still its not working

Following is crashlog

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f1000ef (com.packagename:id/viewPagerBanners) for fragment MainBannerFragmentNew{308cb84 #0 id=0x7f1000ef android:switcher:2131755247:0}
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1292)
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1523)
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1585)
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:2832)
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:2199)
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1323)
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentsToInvisible(FragmentManager.java:2323)
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2136)
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2092)
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1969)
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:620)
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:143)
                                                                         at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1268)
                                                                         at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1116)
                                                                         at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$3.run(ViewPager.java:273)
                                                                         at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
                                                                         at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
                                                                         at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:603)
                                                                         at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

Following is carousel Adapter code

```
public class CarouselAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

private List<CarouselItem> carouselItemsList;

public CarouselAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<CarouselItem> carouselItemsList) {
    super(fm);
    this.carouselItemsList = carouselItemsList;

}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return MainBannerFragmentNew.newInstance(R.drawable.gray_logo, carouselItemsList.get(position));
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return carouselItemsList.size();
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
}
}
```

Following is sliding tab adapter code

```
public class HomeTabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
ArrayList<HomeTabItem> homeTabItems;

public HomeTabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager, ArrayList<HomeTabItem> homeTabItems) {
    super(manager);
    this.homeTabItems = homeTabItems;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    HomeTabItem homeTabItem = homeTabItems.get(position);
    return OfferZoneFragment.newInstance(homeTabItem.getId());

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return homeTabItems.size();
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return homeTabItems.get(position).getTitle();
}
}
```

Every sliding tab fragment has recyclerview this recylerview contains carousel viewpager following is the code in bindview

```
((BannerHolder) holder).viewPager.setAdapter(new CarouselAdapter(fragmentManager, homePageItems.get(position).carouselItems));
                ((BannerHolder) holder).circlePageIndicator.setViewPager(((BannerHolder) holder).viewPager);
                final float density = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
                ((BannerHolder) holder).circlePageIndicator.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
                ((BannerHolder) holder).circlePageIndicator.setRadius(5 * density);
                ((BannerHolder) holder).circlePageIndicator.setFillColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.appthemecolor));
                ((BannerHolder) holder).circlePageIndicator.setPageColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
                ((BannerHolder) holder).circlePageIndicator.setStrokeColor(0x00000000);
                ((BannerHolder) holder).circlePageIndicator.setStrokeWidth(2 * density);
                if (((BannerHolder) holder).viewPager.getAdapter().getCount() <= 1) {
                    ((BannerHolder) holder).circlePageIndicator.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else {
                    ((BannerHolder) holder).circlePageIndicator.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
```

Comment: Using getChildFragmentManager() is the correct way of doing it. Don't know why it is not working in your case. Check if other things are right.

Comment: is `CarouselAdapter` made by you or been borrowed from any library?

Comment: please provide the code which is causing the crash and complete crash log.

Comment: added crash log

Comment: Add ur java code also

Comment: added all possible code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using `getChildFragmentManager` for nested fragments which is correct.

**What you are doing:**

In your case when the fragments wants to be attached to the (child's) viewpager but here the viewpager is not attached to its parent (still detached).

**What you should do:**

Create a custom `ViewPager` override its `onAttachedToWindow` and do the lazy set adapter.

For more details have a look at [IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id for fragment — ViewPager in ViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19888539/illegalargumentexception-no-view-found-for-id-for-fragment-viewpager-in-vie#19900206).

**Update:**

If you want to use `getFragmentManager` or `getSupportFragmentManager` than change the parent class of your `PagerAdapter` from `android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter` to `android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter`.