# Viewpager inside RecyclerView Inside a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview

I Have set of Fragments. Each fragment contains recyclerview and and recyclerview has viewpager as first row.

Now in this set of fragments when I switch from one fragment to another app is crashing following is exception log for it

**Logcat**

```
E/UncaughtException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f1000ef (:id/viewPagerBanners) for fragment MainBannerFragmentNew{a1564b5 #0 id=0x7f1000ef}
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1293)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1528)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1595)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:2888)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:2204)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1326)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1528)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1595)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:2888)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:2204)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1326)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1528)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1595)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:757)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2355)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2146)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2098)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2008)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:710)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

I am passing getChildFragmentManager to Viewpager adapter and I am using FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Inside RecyclerView adapter I am attaching adapter to viewpager as follows

```
switch (holder.getItemViewType()) {
        case TYPE_BANNER:
            if (((BannerHolder) holder).viewPager.getAdapter() == null) {
                ((BannerHolder) holder).viewPager.setAdapter(new CarouselAdapter(fragmentManager, carouselItems));
```

Comment: Perhaps, you aren't setting the id of an xml component in your java class properly. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41806185/nested-fragments-getchildfragmentmanager-causing-crash/41910783)

Comment: means? can you explain in detail

Comment: post complete code

Comment: @alphanso  how you added viewpager inside recyclerview?