# Activity is destroyed without calling onDestroy()

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, ondestroy

My app crashes and gives me the following trace:

```
05-08 08:49:15.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1022): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-08 08:49:15.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1022): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed
05-08 08:49:15.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1022):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1365)
05-08 08:49:15.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1022):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:595)
05-08 08:49:15.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1022):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:578)
05-08 08:49:15.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1022):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:161)
05-08 08:49:15.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1022):     at com.automation.standards.VerticalViewPager.populate(VerticalViewPager.java:965)
05-08 08:49:15.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1022):     at com.automation.standards.VerticalViewPager.populate(VerticalViewPager.java:811)
05-08 08:49:15.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1022):     at com.automation.standards.VerticalViewPager.setAdapter(VerticalViewPager.java:334)
05-08 08:49:15.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1022):     at com.automation.isolace.Lighting.assign_vertical_gangs_swipping(Lighting.java:505)
05-08 08:49:15.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1022):     at com.automation.isolace.Lighting.select_room(Lighting.java:403)
05-08 08:49:15.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1022):     at com.automation.isolace.Lighting$11.onClick(Lighting.java:351)
05-08 08:49:15.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1022):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
05-08 08:49:15.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1022):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
05-08 08:49:15.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1022):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
05-08 08:49:15.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1022):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-08 08:49:15.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1022):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-08 08:49:15.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1022):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
05-08 08:49:15.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1022):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-08 08:49:15.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1022):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-08 08:49:15.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1022):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
05-08 08:49:15.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1022):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
05-08 08:49:15.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1022):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The point is I can't deal with that **Activity Destroy** thing as the Activity is Destroyed without calling `onDestroy()` method and I figured that because I override the onDestroy method but it didn't go through it, also I checked the `isDestroyed()` output but the strange thing it even not giving me `true` despite I put the Line that makes the Activity crashes in a `try-ctach` block, and prints `isDestroyed` in the catch block (which can mean that that line itself is the one which makes the Activity crashes) and here's the code area that the app crashes in:

```
List<Fragment> temp_fragments = fragments; // list of fragments to add to a VerticalViewPager and return it through pageAdapter
TabAdapter2  = new LightVerticalPageAdapter(super.getSupportFragmentManager(), temp_fragments);
Tab2 = (VerticalViewPager) SomeFragment.views.findViewById(R.id.vertical_pager);// "SomeFragment" is the fragment that contains the VerticalPager and the "views" var is the var that stores Fragmrnt view when hitting fragment onViewCreated at the first time
Tab2.setAdapter(TabAdapter2); // HERE IS WHERE THE APP CRASHES AND NOT CALLS ACTIVITY onDestroy()
```

Comment: What is your question? `onDestroy()` not being called is an expected behaviour, you should not rely on it.

Comment: Doy you see this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15207305/getting-the-error-java-lang-illegalstateexception-activity-has-been-destroyed

Comment: @shoerat so, how to know when exactly the Activity is destroyed?

Comment: @pskink So, what i suppose to do to Handle that destroy ?

Comment: @deathember yea i saw it before, and I used it in some level on m y app where i was initializing that stuff from a Fragment not from the Activity itself, as in the Activity I have to deal with the `SupportFragmentManager` as there in no `ChildFragmentManager` in the `FragmentActivity`