# Android Fragment - Application Crashed after Closing Application

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-mapview, android-fragmentactivity

In my application I am using google map in `fragment`. I am using this code for adding `fragment`s.

```
 public void addPage(final BaseFragment pBaseFragment, final boolean isAddToBackStack){
            FragmentTransaction transaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.add(R.id.content_frame, pBaseFragment);
            if (isAddToBackStack) transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();  
    }
```

In `MyMapFragment` I call this for removing map (If I don't do this I got duplicate id for map exception)

```
   public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        Fragment fragment = (getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map_n));
        FragmentTransaction ft = mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.remove(fragment);
        ft.commit();
    }
```

but when I press back button and application is closed I got this error. (in the line ft.commit())

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1365)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:595)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:578)
```

Could anyone tell me what is the solution here how avoid this error I've already stuck on this 3 days.

Comment: Little off topic -- [Crushed vs Crashed](http://www.english-test.net/forum/ftopic11162.html)

for reference check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15207305/getting-the-error-java-lang-illegalstateexception-activity-has-been-destroyed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this way:

```
   @Override
    public void onDestroyView ()
    {
        try{
          SupportMapFragment fragment = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map_n));
          FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
          ft.remove(fragment);
          ft.commit();
        }catch(Exception e){
        }
      super.onDestroyView();  
  }
```

Comment: it's great. I never thought do this way. But anyway it worked. Thanks a lot.