# IllegalStateException : Activity has been destroyed

Tags: android

I am getting IllegalStateException : Activity has been destroyed at `ft.commit()`

I have posted the relevant code and pointed out the error line.I dont know what cause the error.

**Stacktrace:**

```
07-27 02:01:31.776  15571-15571/com.ms.ha E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1397)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:636)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:615)
            at com.ms.ha.activity.MainActivity.articleSelected1(MainActivity.java:248)
            at com.ms.ha.activity.GridActivity3.onClick(GridActivity3.java:98)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I need to move DetailsFragment class onClick the button in GridActivity.Thats why I am using the instance of mainActivity.

**GridActivity3.java:**

```
public class GridActivity3 extends FragmentActivity implements OnClickListener {

   .......
   .......
     @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {

         case R.id.btn_home:

         MainActivity main= new MainActivity();

         main.articleSelected1(6);


         break;

        }
      }
    }
```

**MainActivity.java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnTabChangeListener,ArticleSelectedListener1 {


 @Override
    public void onArticleSelected1(int position)
    {
        articleSelected1(position);

    }

    public void articleSelected1(int position)
    {
 if(position==6)
        {
            //     action_bar_hometext.setText(content);
            FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
            DetailsFragment newFragment = new DetailsFragment();
            ft.replace(R.id.realtabcontent, newFragment);
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            ft.commit();    ----> 248th line

        }
      }
```

I don't know how to solve this error.Anyone can help me with this.Thank you.

Comment: Can you take a look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25185950/java-lang-illegalstateexception-activity-has-been-destroyed

Comment: @Ashwin still getting the same error after adding that onDetach in Fragment class.

Comment: You cannot add fragment using an activity which was in destroyed. Your current activity is GridActivity3.You should try in that.

Comment: @Sar I can't get you.can you elaborate more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is in GridActivity3

```
     MainActivity main= new MainActivity();

     main.articleSelected1(6);
```

Activity class shouldn't be use like that.
You shouldn't create your own instance of Activity, just let Android create and maintain it.
If you want to call `articleSelected1(6);`, put some data to Intent then get it back to check in `MainActivity` then call it.
**UPDATE**
Try this: 
1. In onClick `GridActivity` 
`Intent startMain = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
 startMain.putExtra("position", 6);
startActivity(startMain);`

2. in onCreated of `MainAcitivty`
`int pos = getIntent().getIntExtra("position", 0);
 articleSelected1(pos);`

Comment: I need to move DetailsFragment class onClick the button in GridActivity.

Comment: @User11 I update the answer, Please check it if you still don't know how to pass data to MainActivity

Comment: Very much thank you for your help.Working good.You saved my day.