# How to refresh Child fragment in nested Fragment inside of view pager?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

How to refresh Child fragment in nested Fragment inside of view pager ?

Hi,
i want to refresh my current fragment, i have folow this concept and logic in my project structure,  http://tausiq.wordpress.com/2014/06/06/android-multiple-fragments-stack-in-each-viewpager-tab/

when i am go to back from child to parent i want to refresh my commingup parent fragment,
main problem is when i am going to back, at that time `this` is always null, means `getActivity` not wokring,

i have tryied this code but its not working

```
    09-25 12:48:14.002: E/AndroidRuntime(18584): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    09-25 12:48:14.002: E/AndroidRuntime(18584): Process: com.bbits.nyautogiant, PID: 18584
    09-25 12:48:14.002: E/AndroidRuntime(18584): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed
    09-25 12:48:14.002: E/AndroidRuntime(18584):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1382)
    09-25 12:48:14.002: E/AndroidRuntime(18584):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:595)
    09-25 12:48:14.002: E/AndroidRuntime(18584):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:574)
    09-25 12:48:14.002: E/AndroidRuntime(18584):    at com.bbits.nyautogiant.fragments.SearchResultFragment.refreshListBaseOnRefine(SearchResultFragment.java:1329)
    09-25 12:48:14.002: E/AndroidRuntime(18584):    at com.bbits.nyautogiant.NYAutoGiantActivity.setTitle(NYAutoGiantActivity.java:356)
    09-25 12:48:14.002: E/AndroidRuntime(18584):    at com.bbits.nyautogiant.fragments.RefineFragment$2.onClick(RefineFragment.java:124)
    09-25 12:48:14.002: E/AndroidRuntime(18584):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4424)
    09-25 12:48:14.002: E/AndroidRuntime(18584):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18383)
    09-25 12:48:14.002: E/AndroidRuntime(18584):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    09-25 12:48:14.002: E/AndroidRuntime(18584):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    09-25 12:48:14.002: E/AndroidRuntime(18584):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    09-25 12:48:14.002: E/AndroidRuntime(18584):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
    09-25 12:48:14.002: E/AndroidRuntime(18584):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    09-25 12:48:14.002: E/AndroidRuntime(18584):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    09-25 12:48:14.002: E/AndroidRuntime(18584):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
    09-25 12:48:14.002: E/AndroidRuntime(18584):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
    09-25 12:48:14.002: E/AndroidRuntime(18584):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

`SearchResultFragment` is my upcomming parent fragment,

refreshCode

```
    SearchResultFragment addSearchResultFragment = new SearchResultFragment();

    getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().detach(SearchResultFragment.this).replace(R.id.frmlay_search_result, addSearchResultFragment).attach(addSearchResultFragment)
    .addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

This is my Upcoming parent Fragment xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/frmlay_search_result"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragments.SearchResultFragment" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rel_main_cover"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/backgound" >

                    android:id="@+id/btn_sr_comaprechk"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:enabled="false"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/btn_sr_comaprechk" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: you can find the answer here: 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/15656428/1778343