# Stop handler after the fragment has been destroyed

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-lifecycle, fragment-lifecycle

I have a `Fragment` which sets up a `ListView` and creates a `Handler` to update the `Listview` periodically. However, it looks like the `Handler` still runs after the `Fragment` has been destroyed.

The following is the code.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    //boilerplate code

    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            assignAdapter();
            handler.postDelayed(this, 15000);
        }
    });

    return v;
}
```

Updating the `ListView` after the destruction of the `Fragment` causes the app to crash. How can I cause the `Handler` to stop as the `Fragment` gets destroyed? I would also like to know what effects if any pausing the app has on the `Handler` as well.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need to implement handler like this

```
private Handler myHandler;
private Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //Do Something
    }
};

@Override
public void onDestroy () {

    mHandler.removeCallbacks(myRunnable);
    super.onDestroy ();

}
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to store a reference to your handler and runnable in the fragment, and then when the fragment is destroyed you need to remove callbacks from the handler passing in the runnable.

```
private Handler mHandler;
private Runnable mRunnable;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    //boilerplate code

    mRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            assignAdapter();
            handler.postDelayed(this, 15000);
        }
    };

    mHandler = new Handler(mRunnable);
    mHandler.post();

    return v;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mRunnable);
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: I placed in onDetach().

Comment: The implementation has been changed overtime but still works. You just need to change it to handler = new Handler();
        handler.post(runnable);

Answer (score 2):

Another way of stopping the handler with the use of `WeakReference` to the fragment:

```
static final class UpdateUIRunnable implements Runnable {

        final WeakReference<RouteGuideFragment> weakRefToParent;
        final Handler handler;

        public UpdateUIRunnable(RouteGuideFragment fragment, Handler handler) {
            weakRefToParent = new WeakReference<RouteGuideFragment>(fragment);
            this.handler = handler;
        }

        public void scheduleNextRun() {
            handler.postDelayed(this, INTERVAL_TO_REDRAW_UI);
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            RouteGuideFragment fragment = weakRefToParent.get();

            if (fragment == null || fragment.hasBeenDestroyed()) {
                Log.d("UIUpdateRunnable", "Killing updater -> fragment has been destroyed.");
                return;
            }

            if (fragment.adapter != null) {
                try {
                    fragment.adapter.forceUpdate();
                } finally {
                    // schedule again
                    this.scheduleNextRun();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

where `fragment.hasBeenDestroyed()` is simply a getter for `mDestroyed` property of a fragment:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mDestroyed = true;
}
```

Comment: it is effective way to avoid NPE error while updating view :) good work

Answer (score 0):

Someone posted another question similar and the problem is due to a bug in the `ChildFragmentManager`. Basically, the `ChildFragmentManager` ends up with a broken internal state when it is detached from the `Activity`. Have a look at the [original answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15207305/getting-the-error-java-lang-illegalstateexception-activity-has-been-destroyed)