# change activity inside handler

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, handler

I want to change from my current activity to another while I am inside a Handler. The idea is other code inside the handler will run until a certain condition doesnt match (with increment of the count value every time). When the count value matches the condition I close the activity and move to another.

my code is:

```
  mHandler = new Handler();

        mRunnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

if(count<CONDITION_VALUE)
{
//do other stuff...


    count++;

}else
{



   //change activity...
    finish();

}


                mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 4000);

            }
        };
        mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, (1000));
```

The code is running without any error but the old activity is not being destroyed (i guess) and the new activity is reloaded after every 4 seconds.

I want the new activity to load only once. 
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Finish destroys the activity but the handler is in an async thread in an endless loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, from [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29773973/stop-handler-after-the-fragment-has-been-destroyed)

in your Activity

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
   mHandler.removeCallbacks(mRunnable);
   super.onDestroy();
}
```