# Switching Fragments in TabHost

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Here's my layout design:

```
    MainActivity
         |
    MainFragment
         |
      TabHost
         |
_____________________
|     |     |     |
Tab1  Tab2  Tab3  Tab4
      |
     ft.replace(MainActivityContainer, FragmentThatDoesSomething)
      |
   FragmentThatDoesSomething
```

As you can see, there's a button that does a ft replace on the main activity container and loads FragmentThatDoesSomething to accomplish a task.

In FragmentThatDoesSomething I want to have a button that goes back to Tab2 of the TabHost and keep the tabs.

I use the activity to transfer data between fragments so in the activity is where I would like to perform some ft transaction to get back to tab2.

What's the easiest way to do this?  If I run an ft transaction with the getChildFragmentManager and Tab2's container I run into [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15207305/getting-the-error-java-lang-illegalstateexception-activity-has-been-destroyed)

because I'm using the support v4 Fragment class.

Comment: Use a `ViewPager` and the new `TabLayout`. It is easy to use and implement.

Comment: It looks like TabLayout is API 21 which would cut out a lot of phones.  Looks like something I'll have to do eventually though.  Hmm

Comment: TabLayout is not API 21. Use the new Design Support library.

Comment: Ok I implemented TabLayout and ViewPager.  However now when I try to launch FragmentThatDoesSomething from Tab 2 the fragment overlays against Tab 2's fragment.  I can still see the button from Tab 2 and the background.  I'm trying to launch FragmentThatDoesSomething to replace Tab 2.

Comment: Please just use this example: https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare. Everything is done for you.

Comment: Thanks for the example.  I corrected my mistakes and chose a different path instead of nested fragments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I chose to implement activities as handling nested fragments are a pain.

One gotcha I ran into was sending data back from FragmentThatDoesSomething (now an activity) back to Tab 2.  Because Tab 2 is a nested fragment of MainFragment, I had to override onActivityResult in MainFragment to send data back to the child Tab 2.  I think its because I'm using the v4 Fragment support class.

I did that using [this code.](https://gist.github.com/artem-zinnatullin/6916740)

Answer (score 0):

I would use [addToBackStack(null)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#addToBackStack(java.lang.String)) for my fragment transactions.  Then the button defined in FragmentThatDoesSomething could call [getActivity.onBackPressed()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed%28%29).

At that point it is just a matter of making sure to save state.

```
// MainActivity.java
@Override
public void someCallbackMethod(Object obj1, Object obj2) {
    // have MainActivity store your values and Tab2 fragment accesses data
    // through callback references when Tab2.onCreateView() is called.

    onBackPressed();

    // OR retrieve your Tab2 fragment and manually update values here via 
    // some kind of accessor
}
```

Comment: How would I pass data from FragmentThatDoesSomething to Tab2?  Normally I would use a callback, pass it back to the activity, attach it to a bundle, and ft transact with the fragment or activity.

Comment: Similar approach - have your button event method reference the callback method passing the data along.

Answer (score 0):

compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0' 
I thing you need to use  above material design library to solve your issue .
you can add multiple fragment in one viewPager .

It will provide you more other option to do .