# How to solve fragment overlap?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment

In  **fragment A**, it has `listView`. When the list is clicked, it should pass the data to **fragment B**.

**A.java**

```
 B fragment2 = new B();
 FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
 FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
 fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment1, fragment2);
  fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
  fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

**B.java**

```
public class B extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.b, container, false);
        Log.d("TAG","fragment2");
       return view;
    }
}
```

**a.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/some_text"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>


</FrameLayout>
```

**b.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:fillViewport="false">

    <AbsoluteLayout
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="218dp"
            android:layout_height="47dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Update Page"
            android:id="@+id/textView114"
            android:layout_x="12dp"
            android:layout_y="20dp" />

    </AbsoluteLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

This is how my Fragment A looked like.

[image]

When the list is clicked.

[image]

What's wrong here :?

Comment: Can you post your layout xml file ,and what shout be displayed?

Comment: No errors in log? Where you instantiate `name3` and `date3`?

Comment: @Jamal see my edited post

Comment: how you declare the variables `name3` & `date3`

Comment: can you remove this line   RetrievePage(date,ID); and see if it appears or not

Comment: I have removed `RetrievePage(date,ID);` and add log after `RetrievePage(date,ID);`. The log get called

Comment: Did I need to declare anything in mainfest?

Comment: @John I edited my answer below

Comment: @Jamal noted. I editing my post

Comment: you have to set a background for fragment B layout android:background = "@color/white"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95846/discussion-between-john-and-jamal).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your a.xml use the following :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>


</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think may be your problem in instantiating the `EditText` fields, you'd better declare your items after the view is created, so you have to override the method `onViewCreated` and make your declarations in it, then put your database work in a try-catch block to make sure it isn't the reason of any problems:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    name3 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText9);
    date3 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText12);
    Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
    date = bundle.getString("date1");
    ID = bundle.getString("ID");
    RetrievePage(date, ID);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.b, container, false);
    return view;
}

public void RetrievePage(String date, String id) {
    final String date2 = date;
    final String id2 = id;
    Log.d("m", id2);
    name3.setText("Lim ");
    date3.setText(date2);

    try {
        database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        c = database
                .rawQuery(
                        "SELECT i.Weather FROM Information i LEFT JOIN WorkForce w ON w.TInfo_id = i._id WHERE i.Name = ? AND i._id= ? ",
                        new String[] { String.valueOf("Lim"),
                                String.valueOf(id2) }, null);
        if (c != null) {
            while (c.moveToNext()) {
                Info I = new Info();
                Force WF = new Force();
                String Weather = c.getString(c
                        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MyDatabaseHelper.Weather));

            }

        }
        c.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

---

About fragments overlapping, you must declare each fragment as a separated fragment, and the main `FragmentActivity` is the activity that holds the fragments which in your case must be an empty activity with only the `ViewPager` or `FrameLayout` that contain fragments:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/ac_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.9" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

So, you must have `MainActivity` that contains two fragments `FragmentA` and `FragmentB`

for reference look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32428150/1638739) answer.

Comment: what you must got in the picture 2 and you didn't get ?!!! is fragment B is displayed over fragment A which you don't want ?!!

Comment: ya, I want it display fragment B when list is clicked. But it overlapping

Comment: are you displaying fragment A as the main FragmentActivity ?!!

Comment: No, fragment A is one of the navigation drawer item

Comment: you make what I explained in my updated answer exactly ?!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95845/discussion-between-john-and-muhammed-refaat).

Comment: just have to set a background for fragment B layout android:background = "@color/white"