# Getting the error “Java.lang.IllegalStateException Activity has been destroyed”when change tags

Tags: android, android-fragments

The following link solved a similar problem:  [Getting the error "Java.lang.IllegalStateException Activity has been destroyed" when using tabs with ViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15207305/getting-the-error-java-lang-illegalstateexception-activity-has-been-destroyed)

But I don't use viewpager in my app and my problem appears when I replace fragment after fragment's `onStop()` method. I know it should not to do.
http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss.html

So my question is: How can I solve this condition?

This is my code.the following code is in `AsynTask` so when i change tabs, this condition appear fragments' `onStop` method will be used before the following code.

```
ErrorFragment errorFragment = new ErrorFragment();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt("layoutId", R.layout.errorfragment_mycourse_empty);
errorFragment.setArguments(bundle);
transaction.add(R.id.framelayout_mycoursestudied, errorFragment);
transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();//error code
```

Comment: "I know it shoud not to do"

Comment: but how to code in this condition?data has two different conditions,1:has course 2.is empty.So,it will has two layouts.

Answer (score -1):

My solution is using `EmptyLayout` (define yourself) in xml. If there are two or more conditions, show the `EmptyLayout`, hide the `EmptyLayout` when it has content (has course).