# ClickableSpan is not retaining activity on rotation

Tags: android, illegalstateexception, clickablespan

I'm setting `clickablespan` on a substring of a string and showing a dialogfragment in  `onClick`.

When I click the text for the first time, the dialogfragment shows normally. After dismissing the dialog, I rotate the screen and click the text again, it throws `IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed`.

When I debugged I discovered that the activity is null.

This is my code:

```
String rawAuthor = String.format(getResources().getString(R.string.post_by), name, postDateStr); 

int i1 = rawAuthor.indexOf(" by "); 
int i2 = rawAuthor.indexOf(" on ");
postAuthorDate.setText(rawAuthor, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
postAuthorDate.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
postAuthorDate.setHighlightColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.nav_bg)); 
Spannable spannable = (Spannable)postAuthorDate.getText(); 

ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() { 
   @Override public void onClick(View widget) { 
     Log.d(TAG, "I was clicked"); 
     //mOnTagCatClickedListener.OnTatCatClicked(name, authorId, "Author"); 
     TagCatFragment tagCatFragment = TagCatFragment.newInstance(name, authorId, "Author"); 

     try { 
       tagCatFragment.show(getChildFragmentManager(), "TagCAatFragment");  
     } catch (IllegalStateException e) { 
       e.printStackTrace(); 
     } 
   }
 }; 
 spannable.setSpan(clickableSpan, i1+4, i2, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE); 
 }
```

Stacktrace:

```
07-06 16:56:31.164 2162-2162/com.ozuf.poster W/System.err: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed
07-06 16:56:31.164 2162-2162/com.ozuf.poster W/System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1515)
07-06 16:56:31.164 2162-2162/com.ozuf.poster W/System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:638)
07-06 16:56:31.164 2162-2162/com.ozuf.poster W/System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:617)
07-06 16:56:31.164 2162-2162/com.ozuf.poster W/System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.show(DialogFragment.java:139)
07-06 16:56:31.164 2162-2162/com.ozuf.poster W/System.err:     at com.ozuf.poster.Fragment.DetailsFragment$9.onClick(DetailsFragment.java:474)
07-06 16:56:31.164 2162-2162/com.ozuf.poster W/System.err:     at android.text.method.LinkMovementMethod.onTouchEvent(LinkMovementMethod.java:217)
07-06 16:56:31.164 2162-2162/com.ozuf.poster W/System.err:     at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:8464)
07-06 16:56:31.164 2162-2162/com.ozuf.poster W/System.err:     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8808)
07-06 16:56:31.164 2162-2162/com.ozuf.poster W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2581)
07-06 16:56:31.164 2162-2162/com.ozuf.poster W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
07-06 16:56:31.164 2162-2162/com.ozuf.poster W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2581)
07-06 16:56:31.164 2162-2162/com.ozuf.poster W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
07-06 16:56:31.164 2162-2162/com.ozuf.poster W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2581)
07-06 16:56:31.164 2162-2162/com.ozuf.poster W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
07-06 16:56:31.164 2162-2162/com.ozuf.poster W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2581)
07-06 16:56:31.164 2162-2162/com.ozuf.poster W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
07-06 16:56:31.164 2162-2162/com.ozuf.poster W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2581)
07-06 16:56:31.164 2162-2162/com.ozuf.poster W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
07-06 16:56:31.164 2162-2162/com.ozuf.poster W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2581)
07-06 16:56:31.164 2162-2162/com.ozuf.poster W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
07-06 16:56:31.164 2162-2162/com.ozuf.poster W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2581)
07-06 16:56:31.164 2162-2162/com.ozuf.poster W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
07-06 16:56:31.164 2162-2162/com.ozuf.poster W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2581)
07-06 16:56:31.164 2162-2162/com.ozuf.poster W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
07-06 16:56:31.164 2162-2162/com.ozuf.poster W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2581)
07-06 16:56:31.164 2162-2162/com.ozuf.poster W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
07-06 16:56:31.164 2162-2162/com.ozuf.poster W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2581)
07-06 16:56:31.164 2162-2162/com.ozuf.poster W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
07-06 16:56:31.164 2162-2162/com.ozuf.poster W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2581)
07-06 16:56:31.164 2162-2162/com.ozuf.poster W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
07-06 16:56:31.164 2162-2162/com.ozuf.poster W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2607)
07-06 16:56:31.164 2162-2162/com.ozuf.poster W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1779)
07-06 16:56:31.164 2162-2162/com.ozuf.poster W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2846)
07-06 16:56:31.164 2162-2162/com.ozuf.poster W/System.err:     at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:60)
07-06 16:56:31.164 2162-2162/com.ozuf.poster W/System.err:     at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:60)
07-06 16:56:31.164 2162-2162/com.ozuf.poster W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2568)
07-06 16:56:31.164 2162-2162/com.ozuf.poster W/System.err:     at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:9003)
07-06 16:56:31.164 2162-2162/com.ozuf.poster W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4209)
07-06 16:56:31.164 2162-2162/com.ozuf.poster W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4072)
07-06 16:56:31.164 2162-2162/com.ozuf.poster W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3627)
07-06 16:56:31.164 2162-2162/com.ozuf.poster W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3680)
07-06 16:56:31.164 2162-2162/com.ozuf.poster W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3646)
07-06 16:56:31.164 2162-2162/com.ozuf.poster W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3763)
07-06 16:56:31.164 2162-2162/com.ozuf.poster W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3654)
07-06 16:56:31.164 2162-2162/com.ozuf.poster W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3820)
07-06 16:56:31.164 2162-2162/com.ozuf.poster W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3627)
07-06 16:56:31.164 2162-2162/com.ozuf.poster W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3680)
07-06 16:56:31.164 2162-2162/com.ozuf.poster W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3646)
07-06 16:56:31.164 2162-2162/com.ozuf.poster W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3654)
07-06 16:56:31.164 2162-2162/com.ozuf.poster W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3627)
07-06 16:56:31.164 2162-2162/com.ozuf.poster W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5910)
07-06 16:56:31.164 2162-2162/com.ozuf.poster W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5884)
07-06 16:56:31.164 2162-2162/com.ozuf.poster W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5855)
07-06 16:56:31.164 2162-2162/com.ozuf.poster W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6000)
07-06 16:56:31.164 2162-2162/com.ozuf.poster W/System.err:     at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
07-06 16:56:31.164 2162-2162/com.ozuf.poster W/System.err:     at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
07-06 16:56:31.164 2162-2162/com.ozuf.poster W/System.err:     at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:143)
07-06 16:56:31.164 2162-2162/com.ozuf.poster W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:122)
07-06 16:56:31.164 2162-2162/com.ozuf.poster W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5910)
07-06 16:56:31.164 2162-2162/com.ozuf.poster W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
07-06 16:56:31.164 2162-2162/com.ozuf.poster W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
07-06 16:56:31.164 2162-2162/com.ozuf.poster W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
07-06 16:56:31.164 2162-2162/com.ozuf.poster W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
```

Though I have discovered  that [this is a bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=201383), please is there some sort of temporary fix for it?

Answer (score 0):

You are Right there is bug. the child `FragmentManager` ends up with a broken internal state when it is detached from the `activity`. But simple you call  this to fix it using `onDetach` in your `Fragment`.

```
@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();

    try {
        Field childFragmentManager = Fragment.class.getDeclaredField("mChildFragmentManager");
        childFragmentManager.setAccessible(true);
        childFragmentManager.set(this, null);

    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've actually tried this but it didn't work.

Comment: @Ozuf using this did you get any other error or same error.

Comment: It's as if I didn't try it. I've tried it long before posting this question. I know that this answer was originally given by Marcus Forsell Stahre http://stackoverflow.com/a/15656428/6181476 . But I don't think the solution is for the case of `ClickableSpan` since it didn't work for me.

Comment: @Ozuf did you check this. there are many solution is there with different problem https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=42601

Comment: I have also seen it Sir. That's the bug that made Marcus Forsell Stahre come up with the temporary fix in your answer.