# 'IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed' when adding a tab in tabhost

Tags: java, android, android-tabhost, fragment-tab-host

I want to display a dialog from a listview inside a tabhost. Inside this dialog I want to put another tabhost.

But when I want to add a tab inside the second tabhost I get this stacktrace:

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1549)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:654)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:621)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost.onAttachedToWindow(FragmentTabHost.java:282)
        at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:13491)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2713)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2720)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2720)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2720)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2720)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2720)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2720)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1367)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1126)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6041)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:792)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:596)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:557)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:778)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5721)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1029)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:824)
        at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:11
```

here is how I setup my seconde tabhost:

```
    FragmentTabHost _tabHost  = (FragmentTabHost) view.findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    _tabHost.setup(_context, getSupportFragmentManager(), android.R.id.tabcontent);

    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    extras.putString("profil_id", _id_profil);
    _tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
    _tabHost.addTab(_tabHost.newTabSpec("Posts").setIndicator("Posts"), PopupPrefTab.class, extras);
```

Do you have any ideas to make this work ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15656428 try this link

Comment: I tried that already, but this changed nothing...