# After migrating to AndroidX application crashes with Attempt to invoke androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.isDestroyed() on a null ref

Tags: java, android, androidx

The full stack includes only android core code:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.isDestroyed()' on a null object reference
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performDetach(Fragment.java:2844)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1033)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1237)
    at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:434)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2075)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1865)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1820)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1726)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$2.run(FragmentManagerImpl.java:150)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

It happens when replacing the fragment in main activity:

```java
Runnable mPendingRunnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, fragment);
                fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
            }
        };
```

Comment: I tried without the Runnable, but same result. The cause might be somewhere else.

Answer (score 42):

I found a piece of code in myFragment.onDetach that was causing this:

It was a workaround from [Getting the error "Java.lang.IllegalStateException Activity has been destroyed" when using tabs with ViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15207305/getting-the-error-java-lang-illegalstateexception-activity-has-been-destroyed)

```java
        try {
            Field childFragmentManager = Fragment.class.getDeclaredField("mChildFragmentManager");
            childFragmentManager.setAccessible(true);
            childFragmentManager.set(this, null);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
```

Now, in androidx, this workaround is not needed.

Comment: Thank you so much, I had the exact same problem.

Comment: I believe this should be the accepted answer, found the same snippet in our code that was leading to this issue.

Comment: Thanks. You save my day. :)

Comment: Thank you very much. You save my day

Answer (score 5):

In my module's gradle, I fixed it by reverting

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-beta01'
```

to

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha05'
```

(The above answer with the childFragmentManager stuff did not help.)

Comment: I have filed an Issue for the AppCompat library here:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/136741838

Comment: ur solution worked..but do you know what caused this problem?

Comment: I ran into this, it looks like `androidx.appcompat:1.0.0` does not have this problem, but `androidx.appcompat:1.1.0` split out the Fragment implementation to the `androidx.fragment` library, and this problem shows up sometime after that.

Answer (score 2):

I was straggling last one days about this issue and finally i found the solution. 
Here i am using gradle

```
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.2'
```

and i replaced my fragment using this code.

```
 getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().detach(new    KiKorbo()).replace(R.id.calendar1, caldroidFragment).attach(caldroidFragment)
            .addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Here KiKorbo.java was my parent fragment and i replaced caldroidFragment.

Answer (score 1):

In my module's gradle, I fixed it by reverting

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.5'
```

to

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
```