# IllegalStateException "Activity Destroyed" adding Fragment inside a fragment ( Nested Fragment )

Tags: android, android-fragments, nested, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

Basically this question has been asked many of times [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13757875/getchildfragmentmanager-on-programmatically-dynamically-added-fragments) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14321771/android-nested-fragments-issue-java-lang-illegalstateexception-activity-has-be).Solution given is not working for me. In some corrent answers were not posted by user. 
I want to have nested fragments.  My scenario is as below :

I have one MainActivity, ProductEnterFrag, and ProductListFrag,ProductDetailFrag.

I have add the ProductEnterFrag to MainActivity dynamically by the FragmentManager. Like this :

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.container, new ProductEnterFrag());
ft.commit();
```

ProductEnter layout is as below :

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/fragContainer"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

I have added the ProductListFrag to ProductEnterFrag like this :

```
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
ProductListFrag(new ProductListFrag());
}

public void ProductListFrag(SherlockFragment frag) {
    getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragContainer, frag).commit();
    getChildFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();`
```

}

ProductListFrag whose layout is, as below :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="product1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Now on click of button, I want to add a another fragment say ProductDetailFrag,which should be another child fragment.
When I am trying to add ProductDetailFrag from ProductListFrag like this :

`new ProductEnterFrag().ProductListFrag(new ProductDetailsFrag());`

It is throwing me : `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed`

I am new in nested fragments. Please help me where I am doing wrong. I have stuck with this problem from last 2 days.

Comment: Is there a reason for creating a new instance of `ProductEnterFrag` when adding the `ProductDetailsFrag`? That new instance is not attached to an activity so any fragment transaction will fail.

Comment: @Luksprog then how should i access the function from ProductEnterFrag which creates adds fragment to childFragmentManager. I am new in this. May be I have done something wrong. please guide

Comment: Well I don't know your code, but I'm assuming that you're calling `new ProductEnterFrag().ProductListFrag(new ProductDetailsFrag());` from somewhere in the `ProductListFrag`. In `ProductListFrag` you do have a reference to the wrapper `ProductEnterFrag` through `getParentFragment()`, so if you're in `ProductListFrag` do: `((ProductEnterFrag).getParentFragment()).ProductListFrag(new ProductDetailsFrag());`

Comment: @Luksprog tonnes of thnks... it works. but I have one doubt, when I backpress from the ProductDetailFrag i should move to ProductListFrag. But this is moving me out of application. How could I handle this.

Comment: Your `ProductListFrag` method doesn't add the transaction to the backstack with `addToBackStack(null)`.

Comment: @Luksprog i added `addToBackStack(null)` in that method, though it is move me out of app

Comment: Override `onBackPressed()` in the `MainActivity`. In that method get a reference to the `ProductEnterFrag`, and use `getChildFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount()` on it. If that call returns a value bigger then 0 then do `getChildFragmentManager().popBackStack()` otherwise just call `super.onBackPressed()`;

Comment: @Luksprog it works.. thnks again..

Comment: @nads Your issue resolved ?

Comment: @Luksprog sorry bothering you again. But when i press back,one child fragment in poped up say `ProdDetailFrag` and the `ProdListFrag` is visible. And again when i tap on button in `prodListFrag` to open Detail frag. It is throwing me exception `java.lang.NullPointerException` `at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run` `at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions` could  you please guide me where i m wrong.

Comment: Well, you shouldn't call `getChildFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();`. Try with out it.

Comment: @Luksprog i m not calling `getChildFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();`

Comment: Post a new question providing more details and the entire stacktrace of the exception.

Comment: @Luksprog I am having one doubt for structure of nested fragments. I have created `ProductEnterFrag` a wrapper class to add the child frags of `ProductList`. If I have other menu in `MainActivity` like `ProductList` menu,which has child fragments. Other menu also can have nested fragment. So can I use same Wrapper class `ProductEnterFrag` for all menus or create different wrapper class for each menu[which has nested fragments].

Comment: I'm no sure I understand your problem but yes, if the wrapper fragment allows it you you may reuse it in other places.